# Sliding, hiding, and navigating through divs without javascript

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make a type of interactive slideshow for my website and running into some dead stops in its development. Any direction or assistance on it would be great. The problem I am having is making it responsive.

Here is what im going for: http://adobe.ly/1sRBMLv

I was able to create this initially by using `overflow:hidden;` on a 4000px wide div within a 800px wide visible section. The links then just repositioned the div to show 1 of 5 different 800px wide sections. This idea ultimately needed to be scrapped as it's not responsive.

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dodgrdg3/1/

So far I have just the basic html and css structure but not the function. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: You could use viewport sizes? Have each page based on the viewport size, then move it in direction of viewport size - e.g. +100vw.

Comment: There are a fair number of existing examples out there - try basing your approach off of one of them, and see how far you can get. Here's one that I found after a few minutes Googling: http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/

Comment: @Serlite Thank you but I need it to do more than to just be a slider. If you see the example above it needs HTML within the slide to link to various slides and i haven't found one without javascript that can do that.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the example I linked to, it actually has that kind of functionality - take a look at the row of circles, try clicking on them. They each link to different slides, so you could model your approach after that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the help of @Serlite pointing me in the right direction. I am treating this as a slideshow now. Here is the Fiddle for it working:

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dodgrdg3/3/)

One of my changes were changing.....

This:

```
#a1:target .page { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
#a2:target .page { -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%); -moz-transform: translateX(-200%); }
#a3:target .page { -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%); -moz-transform: translateX(-300%); }
```

Became:

```
#a1:target .pages { left: 0%; }
#a2:target .pages { left: -100%; }
#a3:target .pages { left: -200%; }
```